# Android MD5 checksum of sqlite Db changes after copying

Tags: android, sqlite, compare, md5, checksum

I am providing an SQLite Db packaged with the app which is copied to the /data/data/ folder on the first launch.
The contents of this Db are meant for reading only and are never changed.

If the Db is modified, it is supposed to be provided with the next App Update.
So, I want to implement a procedure where, I was thinking of comparing the MD5 checksum of the packaged Db with the checksum of the Db on the device and copy if found different.

But... after the Db is copied to the device the checksum changes immediately!

Could someone explain if this is the expected behavior, or am I missing something ?

If this is the expected behavior, then what would be the best method to compare the Dbs ?

******* Update *******

I pulled the copied Db from the device and saw that the system adds a "android_metadata" table into the Db. So it is obvious that the checksum differs. This answers my first question.

The second question still remains open.

Comment: Are you using `SQLiteOpenHelper` or [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)?

Comment: @CL. I am using SQLiteOpenHelper. Had looked into SQLiteAssetHelper, but that needs manually setting up the DATABASE_VERSION. I want to avoid this manual intervention and automate the process. This will make it fool-proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the solution was to pre-create the "android_metadata" table with the supported locale values.
If the table exists in the Db, system does not re-create it or change it.
And the checksum comparison works perfectly!

A fool-proof solution exactly the way I love!

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me !